# Why can't my client through his login update the calendar on his page that we created for him via Joomla?

Tags: joomla, calendar

We are having some trouble with a website we recently developed for a client of ours. He is a DJ. For his page, we added a tab that contains a calendar where he can post his events.

Using the admin login, I can successfully post events. However, the client (the DJ) cannot. When I tried using his login, I could not enter events either.  Even stranger, I gave the client the admin login (which I used successfully) and he still couldn't post events! I even walked him through it, and he followed the same instructions, but no luck.

We can't figure this out. [Here is the site](http://www.djking13.com) in case it helps to review it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the DJ's account a "super user" OR if you are using Joomla 2.5 or 3.0 you can change the permissions to give his user type access to the calendar.

Good luck!